# Unable to write Dynamicframe without header

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, aws-glue

Hello I am converting a parquet file to csv and wanna write it without header. I have followed this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format.html).

Below is my code:

```
datasink3 = applymapping1.coalesce(1)

datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = datasink3, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://saphana12/output1"}, format = "csv", format_options = {"writeHeader":'false',"quoteChar":'-1',"separator":'|'}, transformation_ctx = "datasink2")
```

I see the headers are still appearing.

Am I doing something wrong?

Kindly help me out in this

Answer (score 0):

use {"writeHeader": False,"quoteChar":'-1',"separator":'|'}, transformation_ctx = "datasink2")

Instead of declaring 'false' declare False as it is boolean